# How can I add my custom template to the Word home screen ribbon?

Tags: microsoft-office, templates, microsoft-word-2019

I have created a custom template. I can pin it to the "recent" area of the Word home screen but I wish to add it to the selection of templates at the top of the Word home screen (highlighted by a pink box in the picture). How can I achieve this?

[image: Word home screen with template ribbon highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we suggest users save custom templates into **%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates** .You will see your custom templates on the Personal tab when you start an Office program.

[image]

For more information, refer to [Where are my custom templates?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/where-are-my-custom-templates-88ed77ca-df34-49e9-9087-3f01ae296e6e).

Answer (score 1):

When you point the template in the startscreen->personal templates there is a pin to list option in the lower right corner [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5t77.jpg). Click it and the personal template you've selected will be shown in featured template at startup screen [as in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc8Ov.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this (for Word [2013-2021](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#:%7E:text=Custom%20Office%20Templates%20Folder%20(Word,this%20stopped%20with%20Word%202007.))) is to add the template into the "Custom Office Templates" folder in the documents folder. This puts it into the personal tab (New > More templates > Personal) from where it can be pinned in order to show up on the home page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked it out. Re-save your template and check the "Save Thumbnail" option in the dialog when doing so. Then you can click "New" from the home screen, followed by "Personal". Your template appears there and you can then right click it and "Pin to list".

Answer (score 0):

I just found this posting because I was looking for the same information. But I found an easier way that worked for me.

I opened the original template in its folder location then right-click dragged it to the task bar and I got the tool tip: "Pin to Word 2016". I did that and now I can right-click the Word icon (which I have pinned to the task bar) and open the template directly. Very handy!